# Bayes Theorem where the number of tosses depends on tosses

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

There are two fair coins (i.e. Heads and Tails are equally likely for tosses of both). Coin
$1$ is tossed $3$ times. Let $X$ be the number of Heads that occur. After this, Coin $2$ is
tossed $X$ times. Let $Y$ be the number of Heads we get with Coin $2$. The probability
$Pr(X ≥ 2|Y = 1)$ equals ?

I tried to solve it using Bayes' theorem such that

$Pr(X\geq 2|Y=1)={Pr(X\geq 2)\cdot[Pr(Y=1|X=2)+Pr(Y=1|X=3)]\over Pr(X>=2)\cdot[Pr(Y=1|X=2)+Pr(Y=1|X=3)]+Pr(X<2)\cdot[Pr(Y=1|X=0)+Pr(Y=1|X=1)]} $

and i got the answer $7/11$ which seems to be wrong. Can anyone help me understand why this method fails to work?

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to MSE.  You can find a MathJax tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  I'll tidy this one up, and then if you click "edit" you can see what I did.

Comment: Please make the title about the mathematical content of the post, and not something generic like it currently is..

Comment: Your equation is so hard to read I can't even tell if it is one formula or two.  Can you space it out or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$P(X\geq 2 | Y=1) = \frac{P(X \geq 2 \text{ and } Y=1)}{P(Y=1)}$$

We can solve for the numerator and the denominator separately.

$X$ can be $0,1,2,$ or $3$.
$Y$ can equal $1$ in $3$ different ways, because if $X=0$ then $Y$ cannot be $1$.  Each of those is a product, so the denominator is a sum of three terms.

The numerator is easier.  We can split that up into

$$P(X \geq 2 \text{ and } Y = 1) = P(Y = 1 | X \geq 2) \cdot P(X \geq 2)$$

The numerator is two cases, if $X=2$ and if $X = 3$, so the numerator will be a sum of two products:

$$P(Y=1|X=2)\cdot P(X=2) + P(Y=1|X=3)\cdot P(X=3)$$

From there you can put the answer together.  It's hard to read your equation, but I think your problem is that you were trying to factor out a term where there is no common factor.  You have to compute each specific product separately, then add.

---

> I tried to solve it using Bayes' theorem such that
>
> $Pr(X\geq 2|Y=1)={Pr(X\geq 2)\cdot[Pr(Y=1|X=2)+Pr(Y=1|X=3)]\over Pr(X>=2)\cdot[Pr(Y=1|X=2)+Pr(Y=1|X=3)]+Pr(X<2)\cdot[Pr(Y=1|X=0)+Pr(Y=1|X=1)]} $

Problem: $\Pr(Y=1\mid X\geq 2)\neq \Pr(Y=1\mid X=2)+\Pr(Y=1\mid X=3)$ as the Additive Law applies to unions of disjoint *events*, not *conditions*.

Solution: Deal with the union before the conditioning.

In summary:

$\begin{align}\Pr(X\geq 2\mid Y=1)&=\dfrac{\Pr(X=2,Y=1)+\Pr(X=3,Y=1)}{\Pr(X=1,Y=1)+\Pr(X=2,Y=1)+\Pr(X=3,Y=1)}\\[1ex]&=\tfrac{\Pr(X=2)\Pr(Y=1\mid X=2)+\Pr(X=3)\Pr(Y=1\mid X=3)}{\Pr(X=1)\Pr(Y=1\mid X=1)+\Pr(X=2)\Pr(Y=1\mid X=2)+\Pr(X=3)\Pr(Y=1\mid X=3)}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{5}{9}\end{align}$